# Comparing two object arrays in angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to compare two object arrays and check a checkbox for those that have the same object.
below are the object array

```
objArray1 = [
    {b: "AAA", c: 555, d:"RRR", e:"YYY"},
    {b: "WWW", c: 985, d:"DDD", e:234},
    {b: 675, c: 555, d:"RRU", e:"SSS"},
    {b: "TTT", c: 905, d:"PPP", e:"GGG"}
    ]
objArray2 = [
    {b: "AAA", c: 555, d:"RRR", e:"YYY"},
    {b: "TTT", c: 905, d:PPP", e:"GGG"}
    ]
```

I tried using angular.equals but it's not working. Is there a way to do this in the view?

```
<tr ng-repeat="objs in objArray1 ">
  <td>{{objs}}</td>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}" 
             ng-checked="angular.equals(objArray1,objArray2)" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Any solution

Comment: have you tried declaring a function on the $scope which runs the angular.equals check for you and then using the value as the expression for the ng-checked? by having an onclick handler somewhere to execute the function? 

e.g `$scope.compare = function() {
    $scope.result = angular.equals(objArray1, objArray2);
  };` as per AngularJs docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper function to use in view that will check if given object is in the second array.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.objArray1 = [
    {b: "AAA", c: 555, d:"RRR", e:"YYY"},
    {b: "WWW", c: 985, d:"DDD", e:234},
    {b: 675, c: 555, d:"RRU", e:"SSS"},
    {b: "TTT", c: 905, d:"PPP", e:"GGG"}
  ]

  $ctrl.objArray2 =[
    {b: "AAA", c: 555, d:"RRR", e:"YYY"},
    {b: "TTT", c: 905, d:"PPP", e:"GGG"}
  ]

  $ctrl.isInArray = function(obj, objArray) {
    return objArray.findIndex((el) => {
      return angular.equals(obj, el);
    }) >= 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="objs in $ctrl.objArray1">
      <td>{{objs}}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}" ng-checked="$ctrl.isInArray(objs, $ctrl.objArray2)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```